# Prevent super key from going to search bar in Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, fullscreen

I am running an application which must always stay fullscreen. Whenever the super key is pressed, the screen shifts focus to the search bar, sending the fullscreen application to the background. How can I disable this behavior? This keyboard binding is not listed in keyboard shortcuts in settings.

Alternatively, any other strategy which forces the application to remain fullscreen, like a kiosk, is also welcome.

Environment is Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity GUI.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2405352) answered my question. The solution was to run `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''`

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled it for Dell laptop using the this keyboard shortcut -  "Windows Key(winkey) + ALT".